# "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name" when checking for username

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to check a database for a line in a username creation system, to see if the username is in use. Whenever I try to run the program, it tells me there is an invalid column name.

```
bool tooLong = true;
        conn.Open();
        while (tooLong == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a username:");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            if (username.Length > 64)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username too long");
                tooLong = true;
            }
            else if (username.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Username cannot be blank");
                tooLong = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand testUser = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = {username}", conn);
                if (testUser.ExecuteNonQuery() == -1)
                {
                    tooLong = false;
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Username accepted");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username already in use");
                }
            }
```

I have also tried changing

```
SqlCommand testUser = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = {username}", conn);
```

to

```
SqlCommand testUser = new SqlCommand($"SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = '{username}'", conn);
```

but this just lets everything through instead of throwing the error

Comment: The last statement is correctly executing but your code is checking for -1. I suggest you use ExecuteScalar instead. But you should be using [parameters](https://www.dbdelta.com/why-parameters-are-a-best-practice/).

Comment: Person below solved it, along side using ExecuteScalar and testing for null instead. Also changing over to paramaters instead, thanks for the help

Comment: My question is, why use ExecuteNonQuery ... for a query?

Comment: Some tutorial I saw said to use ExecuteNonQuery, so I kind of assumed I can use it everywhere

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, I called out the last statement (with the quotes), which is valid SQL unless the value has ugliness like embedded single quotes.

Comment: @DanGuzman yah somehow I glossed over that line... twice heh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make sure you are not missing the schema in the table name. They are not always a `dbo.Users`. Try copying the SQL as you have it, paste it in SSMS, and simply replace the `{username}` with an actual 'userName'.

Also, instead of passing in your variable directly, you should add a parameter to prevent SQL injection. Store your SQL query in a variable (here: `sqlQuery`). Then, add your `UserName` as a parameter.

**Note**: by adding the parameter as below, you will not need to pass in the single quotes.

```
const string sqlQuery = @"SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = @userName";

var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = userName
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem with `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: PS: The `$` for `string sqlQuery` is unneeded

Comment: Using parameters can increase performance of SQL Server. If you are using parameters, you have same command every time and SQL server can do some predictions for future requests. It is important for bigger solutions.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point derpirscher. It would with ExecuteScalar(). I should have read the rest of his method. I assumed he wanted the value returned from the query. My bad, good catch.

Comment: Oh yeah Julian, just a copy paste oversight from the original query.

Answer (score 1):

You have no quotes `'` around your `{username}` thus, the query results in something like

```
select username from mytable where username = john
```

And I don't suppose you have a column named `john` thus, the `Invalid column` error. You should use parameterized queries instead.

Futhermore [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery) for a SELECT will always return `-1` because it's defined that way. So you could for instance return the count of matching rows. And if the count is 0, the username was not found.

```
var command = new SqlCommand("select count(username) from mytable where username = @username", theconnection);
command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = username;
var usercount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

if (usercount == 0) {
   //not found
} else {
   //found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the code, thanks for the help.
Changed to

```
                SqlCommand testUser = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @userName;", conn);
                testUser.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                testUser.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = username;
                if (testUser.ExecuteScalar() != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Username already in use");
                }
                else
                {
                    tooLong = false;
                    conn.Close();
                    Console.WriteLine("Username accepted");
                }
            }
```

I'm also changing my other queries to use parameters instead.

Comment: That's quite dangerous, as `ExecuteScalar()` could also return a `DBNull.Value` from a `SELECT *` and `DBNull.Value != null` evaluates to `true`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If you got an answer to your question and you accepted it with a green tick, *do not* post your own answer showing the corrections you made. It's noise. You're free to answer your own question but in that case you should just accept your own. Except, a code only answer doesn't explain anything so it's just more noise

Comment: Furthermore, is your column *really* Varchar or is it Nvarchar? Because if it's the latter then you have a bug

Comment: Would `if (testID.ExecuteScalar() == null | testID.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value)` work? Also, its all nchars

Comment: It would (if you add the missing `|` for the or), but this way you are executing your query twice ...

Comment: I'm storing the query result in a variable now, and testing against that instead `object testUserResult = testUser.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: You should specify the length of the parameter also `testUser.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000).Value = username;` And don't use `select *`